# App Maker Multi Select?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

So I'm quite new to Google App Maker and what the situation is is that I have one datasource which has a section that I would like to use a multiselect for. I've followed the Partner Management template to try and understand how relations work a bit better and I've read all of the documentation on them but despite what I do the multi select either always unticks everything by default when I come out of the edit dialog or it changes the values for all of the multiselects within each request. I'm struggling to bind the data. I know it's hard to describe without showing you but basically I just wondered if anyone would be able to explain to me a bit better how exactly I would get a multiselect to work and keep it's value for each individual request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in datasource only one item can be selected, you can add checkbox column, so you will be able to get list of checked items.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, we've just found that by binding the values via @widget.parent.parent.datasource.item.[your datasource].[whichever parameter]. Options: @datasource.[your datasource].items and names: Options: @datasource.[your datasource].items..[parameter] it works! I can have multiple selections and it's also in relation to each request! :)